# How to show a long list without using a ListView

Tags: android, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I am working on an exercise program, and one part is to pick an exercise, then how often you do it, with how much weight.

So, I want all this information on one screen, so going to a `ListView` would be annoying, I believe.

But, there may be over 100 exercises, so my current approach of using a `Spinner` has a problem.

It would seem that if my list is sorted, then if you can hit a key and jump to that letter then it would speed up searching for the user.

So, would it make sense to have a custom component that is basically just a dropdown list (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511458.aspx) or is there a better way to allow users to navigate a long list without going to a new screen?

Comment: "So, I want all this information on one screen, so going to a ListView would be annoying, I believe." -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare - I am trying to reduce the number of clicks, as I think it is bad design to have them going to more screens than absolutely needed.

Comment: But there is only one screen. It has a `ListView` in it. Moreover, your proposed solutions add clicks, rather than remove them. For example, your theorized drop-down requires you to open the drop-down, then find your choice, rather than just finding your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try autocomplete widget that is described here

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Comment: I think this may be a better choice, since it searches the start of each word, so you can quickly see what type of squats you want to do.